# Part of speech and usage of "in person"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, adverbs

Is "in person" an adjective or adverb, describing the person or the action being done?

> - The artist will be in person, painting.
> - The artist will be painting in person.

Which is correct?

Comment: It is an adverbial constituent, so it functions like an adverb. You could say it is an adverbial phrase of manner.

Answer (score 3):

The second "The artist will be painting in person" is correct. The first sentence is confusing, because the action is "will be painting" not "will be a person"; you could also say "The artist will personally paint", or "The artist will be present to paint" or "Live and in person, the artist is here to paint".

Comment: Or simply *The artist will be there in person, painting.*

Comment: Or the even simpler *The artist will be painting*. I think we can rely on the reader to infer that it is a person (and the person was there) painting.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct, as the first one meaning is not clear.

To express something, the sentence should be sound to mean.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the phrase "in person"  in this sentence is incorrect.

It is used in contexts where there is ambiguity regarding the physical presence of the individual being addressed or referred to and using the phrase removes the ambiguity.

For example:

"We would like to have a word with you, in person."

"The president will be available, in person, to take your questions."

EDIT: The sentence  "Could you deliver this package, in person?"   is also similar to 
"The artist will be painting in person." as they are both overemphasizing the physical presence that is already implied.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course the artist will be painting “in person!” Assuming that a future event is what is tangentially being discussed, one could say/write, “The artist will be present, painting.”